# Blade and JavaScript - How to remove white spaces from string inside attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

So I have a title attribute inside my elements because I want to use Bootstrap's tooltip. However I may have different options depending on the data. I am doing a @foreach loop between the quotes of the title attribute. However if there is more than one thing to be printed the tooltip box gets broken and I get this enormous whitespace. I think a possible solution/workaroud would be to use JS or JQuery to trim the whitespaces. How can I do that? here is my code and how the tooltip looks like if there are more than one iterations.

```
<option data-toggle="tooltip" title="
@foreach($availableOption->optionIncompatibilities as $optionIncompatibility)
     Not available when:  {{ $optionIncompatibility->disabled_by_id1 }}
@endforeach
">
```

[image]

Other solutions and advice would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 

$tooltip = '';

?>
@foreach($availableOption->optionIncompatibilities as $optionIncompatibility)
    <?php
    $tooltip .=  'Not available when:' . $optionIncompatibility->disabled_by_id1;
    ?>
@endforeach

<option data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ $tooltip }}">
```

Make the loop and create the tooltip value first before using it.

Note: I hope this will help you, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: Just tested it. Works like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad that it helped you :).